# Why is Satan, clearly a living being (fallen angel) who spoke to God and Jesus, called "the satan"?

Tags: satan

I first saw 'the satan' on Wikipedia. Satan is listed 49 times in the Hebrew Bible and New Testament. I did not look at every verse, but of the many I did review, not one is translated 'the satan'.  Satan is designated as a person / being because he speaks with others. He 'works', he 'hinders', 'tempts', is a 'liar', etc. Jesus 'rebuked' Satan and told him to 'get out of here' (paraphrased). He argued with God (Job).

Per Strongs Concordance:
4567. Satanas
Search for G4567 in KJVSL
satanaV Satanas sat-an-as'
of Chaldee origin corresponding to 4566 (with the definite affix); the accuser, i.e. the devil:--Satan.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hebrew noun *satan*, along with related nouns and verbs, are semi-common in the Hebrew scriptures. These terms are used in a variety of contexts and refer to a variety of individuals. In English, *satan* literally means something like 'opponent', 'adversary', or 'accuser'. The term is not a name, but a descriptive label for the action someone is taking.

In Numbers 22.22,32, for example, it is an angel explicitly acting on God's behalf who is identified as a satan, meaning 'adversary'.

In 1 Samuel 29.4, it is David who is called the *satan* (adversary) of the Philistines.

In other passages, *satan* refers to humans acting as enemies to the king of Israel (2 Samuel 19.22; First Kings 5.4; 11.14,23,25).

In yet another, the term *satan* describes an accuser in a court setting, who stands to the right of the person being accused (Psalm 109.6).

By the time we arrive at the new testament, the term is certainly used in a more systematic sense for a particular angel figure (i.e. the angel we find in Job 1-2 and Zechariah 3), but nothing in the text of either the Hebrew scriptures or the new testament suggests it should be understood as a name.

However, simply calling this angel **the** *satan* does not mean it is being reduced to an inanimate object or a symbol. It simply describes the kind of action this angel takes: he is the 'accuser' or 'adversary', i.e. he is the *satan*. This is no different than calling someone 'the king'.

Comment: I now understand "the satan" = "the accuser".  Could be 'the defendant" though not giving a name.  What about Lucifer, the Devil? What I mean is, when do we shift from labels to what we term names?  Moses = Moses, to us, and we don't call him "drawn from the water"... I suppose I am answering my own question; in our culture Satan, the  Devil, and Lucifer all typically refer to a fallen angelic being, or at least it used to...

Comment: @user3380 You've asked a new question in a comment. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button (although you should also search the site for 'Lucifer' first, as we may have already answered your question).

Answer (score 1):

הַשָּׂטָן ha-Satan, is the term used for accuser or opposer; he opposes God(and man), and stands in the way to accuse them:(Zech. 3:1-2)

> **And he shewed me Joshua the high priest standing before the angel of
>   the Lord, and Satan standing at his right hand to resist him. 2 And
>   the Lord said unto Satan, The Lord rebuke thee, O Satan**

In another example, Satan deliberately seeks to oppose men:(Job 1:9-12)

> *Then Satan answered the Lord, and said, Doth Job fear God for nought?
>   10 Hast not thou made an hedge about him, and about his house, and
>   about all that he hath on every side? thou hast blessed the work of
>   his hands, and his substance is increased in the land. 11 But put
>   forth thine hand now, and touch all that he hath, and he will curse
>   thee to thy face. 12 **And the Lord said unto Satan, Behold, all that he
>   hath is in thy power; only upon himself put not forth thine hand**. So
>   Satan went forth from the presence of the Lord.*

What one must very carefully recognize is that **God does not afflict Job, Satan does.**> In Rev. 20:1-3, it says:

> And I saw an angel come down from heaven, having the key of the
>   bottomless pit and a great chain in his hand. 2 **And he laid hold on
>   the dragon, that old serpent, which is the Devil, and Satan,** and bound
>   him a thousand years, 3 and cast him into the bottomless pit, and shut
>   him up, and set a seal upon him, that he should deceive the nations no
>   more, till the thousand years should be fulfilled: and after that he
>   must be loosed a little season.

This equates him with "serpent" that tempted Eve in the Garden of Eden(Gen. 3:1-4), and it is important to note; because although angels have names(Michael, Gabriel, Raphael(from the Book of Tobit), **fallen angels do not**; rather, they take on the 'name' of their demonic activity(spirit of infirmity, deaf and dumb spirit, or, if they are a 'higher order', "Prince of Persia", "Prince of Greece", and it could be said of Satan himself "King of Tyre":(Ezek. 28:12-14)

> "Son of man, take up a lamentation upon the king of Tyrus, and say
>
> > unto him, Thus saith the Lord God; Thou sealest up the sum, full of
> >     wisdom, and perfect in beauty. 
> >     13 Thou hast been in Eden the garden of God; every precious stone was
> >     thy covering, the sardius, topaz, and the diamond, the beryl, the
> >     onyx, and the jasper, the sapphire, the emerald, and the carbuncle,
> >     and gold: the workmanship of thy tabrets and of thy pipes was prepared
> >     in thee in the day that thou wast created.
> >     14 Thou art the anointed cherub that covereth; and I have set thee so:
> >     thou wast upon the holy mountain of God; thou hast walked up and down
> >     in the midst of the stones of fire. 
> >     **Thou wast perfect in thy ways from the day that thou wast created,
> >     till iniquity was found in thee**.
> >     16 By the multitude of thy merchandise they have filled the midst of
> >     thee with violence, and thou hast sinned: therefore I will cast thee
> >     as profane out of the mountain of God: and **I will destroy thee, O
> >     covering cherub, from the midst of the stones of fire.**

"

I believe that this is because they already are under judgement; we read in Matt. 25:41,

> **Then shall he say also unto them on the left hand, Depart from me,
>   ye cursed, into everlasting fire, prepared for the devil and his
>   angels:**

Hell was prepared for Satan and his fallen angels-there is no repentance allowed. Therefore, Lucifer(Light-Bearer) of Isa. 14:12, becomes ha-Satan, the opposer.

> .